# Skipping tests with certain attributes in green like you can with nosetests

Tags: python-green

I'm trying to get [green](https://github.com/CleanCut/green) to skip tests with certain attributes (e.g. `ATTR=!slow`) like you can do in nose (with `@attr('slow')` or just by assigning the test a property):
http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html

http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html

> -a=ATTR, --attr=ATTR
>   Run only tests that have attributes specified by ATTR [NOSE_ATTR]

Anyone know the syntax (assuming it's possible)?

Comment: Sorry for the 4-week delay in response! I set up an RSS feed for the python-green tag so that I get alerted quickly to new questions in the future, so (hopefully) this kind of delay won't happen again.  That's an interesting feature.  Do you use that feature a lot?

Comment: My teammates use it a lot, as do others in the company, so it's a bit of a stumbling block to get them to adopt it without this feature, unfortunately.

Comment: Good to know.  I added an issue to consider adding support for it: https://github.com/CleanCut/green/issues/89

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible with green.